# How to pass ControllerContext to Attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I would like to use information from the ControllerContext or ActionContext from inside the Attribute\Filter constructor. How can i do so? Tried to pass the ControllerContext as a parameter to the attribute from the action but with no success.

Comment: Filter instances are `not` created on a per-request basis and so you cannot pass the ControllerContext(which is per-request specific context) to the filter constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
           var controllerContext =  filterContext.Controller.ControllerContext;
```

on action executing. You **cannot** have the context on construction

Answer (score 0):

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult VideoStream(int id = 0)
    {
     }
    public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
    {
        string routedata = context.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["id"].ToString();
        //The File Path 
        var videoFilePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath("~/CombineFile/Tanvir.mp4");
        //The header information 

    }
```